# how to give chapter, section and subsection headings identical flushleft indentation in a TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation

How do I change the indentations of \section \subsection in the Table of Contents so that they line up flush left at the same indentation of the chapter heading? I am using book class format.

My code looks like this

```
\renewcommand*{\contentsname}{\normalsize Table of Contents}
{\tableofcontents}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter} {\trjnfamily{\fontsize{13pt}{13pt}\selectfont PART I THE CODEX AND ITS HISTORY}}
\chapter* {\trjnfamily{\fontsize{18pt}{18pt}\selectfont PART I\\ THE CODEX AND ITS HISTORY}}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{{\large }}
\include{chapter1} %Physical description
\include{chapter2} %Provenance
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\trjnfamily{\fontsize{13pt}{13pt}\selectfont PART II LITERARY SOURCES}}
\chapter* {\trjnfamily{\fontsize{18pt}{18pt}\selectfont PART II\\ LITERARY SOURCES}}\
\include{chapter3}%Links
\include{chapter4}%Conventions
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\trjnfamily{\fontsize{13pt}{13pt}\selectfont
PART III INTERPRETING TEXT AND IMAGE}}
\chapter* {\trjnfamily{\fontsize{18pt}{18pt}\selectfont PART III\\ INTERPRETING THE TEXT}}
\include{chapV}
\include{chapW}
\include{chapY}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This fragment isn't compilable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tocflat` option of `tocstyle` package:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[tocflat]{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{standard}
\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \Blinddocument
  \Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

With `tocloft`, you can set indents using

```
\cftsetindents{<entry>}{<indent>}{<numwidth}
```

Here `entry` is `chapter`, `section` etc, `<indent>` is indent and `<numwidth>` is the width reserved for typesetting the entry number.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\cftsetindents{chapter}{0pt}{3em}
\cftsetindents{section}{0pt}{3em}
\cftsetindents{subsection}{0pt}{3em}
\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \Blinddocument
  \Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]